# How to normalize or standardize data when using the ReLu activation function in an LSTM Model

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Should I normalize the LSTM input data between 0 and 1 or -1 and 1 and why?
And will normalizing my input data reduce or improve the training time of my LSTM model?
This is because my LSTM model is taking too long to train but giving very good results.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's good to normalize inputs before feeding them to neural networks. Both [0, 1] and [-1, 1] normalizations are fine, depending on the type of architecture you will be using. But normalization usually doesn't affect the training time of the model.